# Jquery slider global javascript variables

Tags: jquery, variables, slider, global

i have a problem with accessing global variables, would like to access

```
selection1 = $("#slider").slider( "value" );
selection2 = $("#slider2").slider( "value" );
```

inside the jQuery function simply by calling the calcTmpl(selection1, selection2) with the selections but this does not seem to work by declaring the variable outside the function like so: `var selection1 = $("#slider").slider( "value" );`

the slider then dissapears.

this is the code for the calculations the sliders perform. And this works, just that i dont want to keep setting the selection1 and 2 over and over again.

Any ideas why this isnt working?

```
var selection1;
var selection2;
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 5000000,
    min: 100000,
    max: 10000000,
    slide: function() {
        selection1 = $("#slider").slider("value");
        selection2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");
        calcTmpl(selection1, selection2);
    },
    change: function() {
        selection1 = $("#slider").slider("value");
        selection2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");
        calcTmpl(selection1, selection2);
    }
});

$("#slider2").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 50000,
    min: 100,
    max: 100000,
    slide: function() {
        selection1 = $("#slider").slider("value");
        selection2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");
        calcTmpl(selection1, selection2);
    },
    change: function() {
        selection1 = $("#slider").slider("value");
        selection2 = $("#slider2").slider("value");
        calcTmpl(selection1, selection2);
    }
});​
calcTmpl(5000000,50000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var selection1 = 5000000,
    selection2 = 50000;

$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: selection1,
    min: 100000,
    max: 10000000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        selection1 = ui.value;
        calcTmpl(selection1, selection2);
    }
});

$("#slider2").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: selection2,
    min: 100,
    max: 100000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        selection2 = ui.value;
        calcTmpl(selection1, selection2);
    }
});
```